# Protractor How to select almost duplicate element using xpath

Tags: protractor, element

I have a page with two tables that are very similar, each with a VIEW ALL text to link to two different pages. How do I differentiate the two different VIEW ALL text links?

```
<a href="/#/notifications"><span class="d-inline float-right btn btn-clear">VIEW ALL</span></a>

<a href="/#/accounts/all"><span class="d-inline float-right btn btn-clear">VIEW ALL</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try differentiate with href

```
var notificationlink = element(by.css("a[href*=notifications]"));
var accountslink= element(by.css("a[href*=accounts]"));
```

If you are particularly looking for xpath then you can use this assuming the notifications link is the first element on the page and accounts link is second element

```
var links = element.all(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'VIEW ALL')]"));
links.get(0).click() //this will clicks on Notifications link
links.get(1).click() //this will clicks on Accounts link
```